# Copy part of image to another image with EmguCV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I want to copy a center part (Rectangle) of my image to a completely white `Mat` (to the same position).

Code:

```
        Mat src = Image.Mat;
        Mat dst = new Mat(src.Height, src.Width, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        dst.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 255, 255).MCvScalar);

        Rectangle roi = new Rectangle((int)(0.1 * src.Width), (int)(0.1 * src.Height), (int)(0.8 * src.Width), (int)(0.8 * src.Height));

        Mat srcROI = new Mat(src, roi);

        Mat dstROI = new Mat(dst, roi);

        srcROI.CopyTo(dstROI);

        //I have dstROI filled well. CopyTo method is doing well. 
        //However I have no changes in my dst file.
```

However I'm getting only white image as a result - `dst`. Nothing inside.

What i'm doing wrong?

using EmguCV 3.1

**EDIT**

I have a `dstROI` Mat filled well. But there is a problem how to apply changes to original `dst` Mat now.

Changing `CopyTo` like this:

```
  srcROI.CopyTo(dst);
```

causes that dst is filled now with my part of src image but not in the centre like i wanted

**EDIT 2**

```
 src.Depth = Cv8U
```

As you suggested I check a value of `IsSubmatrix` property.

```
   Console.WriteLine(dstROI.IsSubmatrix);         
   srcROI.CopyTo(dstROI);
   Console.WriteLine(dstROI.IsSubmatrix);
```

gives output:

```
   true
   false
```

What can be wrong then?

Comment: `srcROI.CopyTo(dst);` -- If you want to put it in the center, then you should keep the `dstROI` as you had it.

Comment: If i will do `srcROI.CopyTo(dstROI);` then `dst` is not changing at all :(

Comment: Oooh... `src.Height * Ratio, src.Width * Ratio` -- What's `Ratio` and what's its intent in this algorithm?

Comment: @DanMašek in this case it was 1.0 so i removed it from code snippet. I have tried to save image from `dst` just after `CopyTo(dstROI)` but still apears to be completly white

Comment: Aww, false lead, that could have had an effect.OK, what's `Depth` and `NumberOfChannels` of `src`? What's the value of `IsSubmatrix` of `dstROI` before and after the call to `CopyTo`?

Comment: @DanMašek check edit please :)

Comment: @ilovkatie - Have you found your answer yet?

Answer (score 2):

Ancient question, I know, but it came up when I searched so an answer here might still be being hit in searches. I had a similar issue and it *may* be the same problem. If `src` and `dst` have different numbers of channels or different depths, then a new `Mat` is created instead. I see that they both have the same depth, but in my case, I had a single channel going into a 3 channel `Mat`. If your `src` is not a 3 channel `Mat`, then this may be the issue (it might be 1 (gray) or 4 channel (BGRA) for example).

Comment: Thank you.  I was attempting to copy a bgr to bgra and was completely lost as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [operator precedence rules of C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) a type cast has higher priority than multiplication.

Hence `(int)0.8 * src.Width` is equivalent to `0 * src.Width`, and the same applies to the other parameters of the `roi` rectangle. Therefore the line where you create the `roi` is basically

```
Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
```

Copying a 0-size block does nothing, so you're left with the pristine white image you created earlier.

---

### Solution

Parenthesize your expressions properly.

```
Rectangle roi = new Rectangle((int)(0.1 * src.Width)
    , (int)(0.1 * src.Height)
    , (int)(0.8 * src.Width)
    , (int)(0.8 * src.Height));
```

Comment: Good point, I have fixed it. My rectangle is now like: `{X=204,Y=204,Width=1638,Height=1638}`. However - still no changes. White board like before.