# Can't use Emgu Mat.CopyTo to write into a submatrix

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, mat

I've never had an issue with this in C++ when writing with OpenCV, but I will admit I haven't tried this exactly, so I may be missing something obvious, or it may be Emgu related.

I'm trying to write a matrix into a submat using the Mat. CopyTo method, but it seems to always create a new Matrix. Here is a working example:

```
    public static void ExampleOne()
    {
        // Create the full image
        Mat fullImage = new Mat(100, 100, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        fullImage.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 255, 255).MCvScalar);

        // Create an ArUco marker
        Mat marker = new Mat(40, 40, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        Dictionary arucoDictionary = new Dictionary(Dictionary.PredefinedDictionaryName.Dict6X6_250);
        ArucoInvoke.DrawMarker(arucoDictionary, 1, 20, marker);

        // Create a section of the full image for the ArUco Marker to sit in
        Mat section = new Mat(fullImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), marker.Size));
        section.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 0, 0).MCvScalar); // Set to blue for testing

        // Debug stuff
        bool sectionIsSubMatrix1 = section.IsSubmatrix;
        IntPtr sectionDataPointer1 = section.DataPointer;

        // Convert the ArUco marker to the same depth and channels as the original
        Mat marker8U = new Mat(marker.Size, section.Depth, section.NumberOfChannels);
        marker.ConvertTo(marker8U, marker8U.Depth);

        // Copy the marker into the section
        marker8U.CopyTo(section);

        // Debug stuff
        bool sectionIsSubMatrix2 = section.IsSubmatrix;
        IntPtr sectionDataPointer2 = section.DataPointer;

        Debug.WriteLine("Section 1 {0} 0x{1:X}", sectionIsSubMatrix1, (long)sectionDataPointer1);
        Debug.WriteLine("Section 2 {0} 0x{1:X}", sectionIsSubMatrix2, (long)sectionDataPointer2);
    }
```

The result is that I get an ArUco marker in marker and marker8U, marker8U is copied to setion, but in doing so, section gets a new Mat header and is no longer a submat in fullImage. The fullImage gets a blue box in the corner.

I'm trying to copy the contents of the matrix with the ArUco marker into the section of the fullImage.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Of course, after posting, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335774/copy-part-of-image-to-another-image-with-emgucv  - but no answers there either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. As is often the case, the problem was not where I thought it was. The issue was with the conversion:

```
    // Convert the ArUco marker to the same depth and channels as the original
    Mat marker8U = new Mat(marker.Size, section.Depth, section.NumberOfChannels);
    marker.ConvertTo(marker8U, marker8U.Depth);
```

In this, `marker8u` is created with 3 channels, and `marker` has 1 channel; but `ConvertTo` only changes the depth, not the number of channels. Instead of replicating the single channel across the 3 channels in `marker8u`, it simply made a new `Mat` with 1 channel - essentially doing nothing.

The fix was simply; replace the call to `ConvertTo` with a call to `CvtColor` as follow:

```
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(marker, marker8U, ColorConversion.Gray2Bgr);
```

This simply replicates the channel across three channels, and this time, the call to `CopyTo` worked because the channels and depth matched.

Comment: In case anyone checks, I kept this question and answer separate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335774/copy-part-of-image-to-another-image-with-emgucv because I cannot tell if they are the same problem, though they may be.